# remove the print button on AddThis widget

Tags: javascript, ajax, share, addthis, sharethis

Is there a way to just remove the print button from AddThis widget ?

I tried the base parameters that allows to control the specific buttons to display, but this is not what i want to do. I want to let AddThis system determine which share buttons to display to the user, BUT i don't want the print button

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-55a32eeb2d39aac3\" async=\"async\"></script>
```

Comment: this code is nont releavant to answer. post more code.

Comment: Useless answer. There is no other code than this. Why is this even +1'ed ?

Answer (score 2):

From addthis support "remove print button"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var addthis_config =
{
services_exclude: 'print'
}
</script>
```

Did the trick for me but then it put "PrintFriendly" on top ?
So I did ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var addthis_config =
{
 services_exclude: 'print, printfriendly'
}
</script>
```

Now I only need to know if I can order these things, perhaps you need to use "services_expanded:" instead.  Where instead of excluding, you list only the ones you want, and I suppose it would give in order you specified. (But I haven't tried it)

Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var addthis_config =
{
 services_expanded: 'facebook, twitter, linkedin, '
}
</script>
```

Also seems to need to be lowercase....  services_exclude: 'PrintFriendly'  did not exclude until changed to 'printfriendly'

Also in case you didnt know -the script needs to be somewhere in your pages,  included before close body tag is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You can select your own services in the tool's settings page itself. There's an option "Select Your Own" under Services. Enable that option and drag the services from Available Services to Selected Services and update the changes made:

[image: *Select Your Own* option in the settings page]

Comment: My question clearly states i don't want to use this option, i want to let AddThis automatically personalize the sharing buttons for each visitor, i just don't want the print button to be displayed